# delete mailgun, maillist recipients from c# using mailgun pariticular domain api

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailgun

Here is the function to delete a particular list recipient mail address, But this function doesn't work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DelteRecipients("testList", "test@test.com";   
}  

public void DelteRecipients(string listName,string recipientMail)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");

    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                                      "myDomainApi");
    RestRequest reqForTotal = new RestRequest();
    reqForTotal.Resource = ""lists/{list}/members";
    reqForTotal.AddParameter("list", listName, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    reqForTotal.AddParameter("address", recipientMail);
    reqForTotal.Method = Method.DELETE;
    client.Execute(reqForTotal);   
}
```